# How to per click call function from Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have `ParameterService` with redirect method. I want to call it every time I click the Back button.

**parameter.service.ts**

```
export class ParameterService {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any) {
    const url = document && document.location && document.location.href;
  }

  redirectToParameterForm(document: any) {
    document.location.href = document.location.href + './login.html';
  }
}
```

**not-finde-component.ts**

```
import { any } from 'codelyzer/util/function';

export class NotFindeComponent {

  constructor(private parameterService:ParameterService) {}

  back() {
    this.parameterService.redirectToParameterForm(any);
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<button class="btn btn-info" (click)="back()">Back</button>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined at
>   ParameterService.

Comment: not getting `href` element verify on the time of call `href` it will be there of not or `if (document.location.href) {this.parameterService.redirectToParameterForm(any);}` add this one for check and then call

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you, could you please write an example?

Comment: ok youo want to redirect every time if you click on back button go to the login page?

Comment: use `Router` to get current route value and also use for `navigate` to `login` component